# How to replace isMirrored with isVideoMirrored

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, avfoundation

I have inspired myself from [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) code, but I am a little confused about object `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, which seems to have a deprecated method `isMirrored` since **iOS 6**. Unfortunately, this method is replaced with another one, that is in totally different class! It is now in object `AVCaptureConnection` - `isVideoMirrored`. I am not using this object in my code and I have no idea how to use it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [apple's source code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Classes_AVCamViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Classes_AVCamViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10), try changing:

```
if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer isMirrored])
{
    viewCoordinates.x = frameSize.width - viewCoordinates.x;
}
```

For:

```
BOOL videoMirrored;
if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer respondsToSelector:@selector(connection)])
{
    videoMirrored = captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.isVideoMirrored;
}
else
{
    videoMirrored = captureVideoPreviewLayer.isMirrored;
}

if (videoMirrored)
{
    viewCoordinates.x = frameSize.width - viewCoordinates.x;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: Code written in browser :/

Comment: Great! I didn't know that `.connection.isVideoMirrored;` has to be called on the preview layer. I was always getting `isVideoMirrored == NO` when using connection object from `- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection`.

Comment: This is one of the gotchas of Objective-C, when you send a message to an instance that doesn't respond to that message, the runtime always returns 'nil', so your code was not returning 'NO' but 'nil' ... there was a time when the runtime would differentiate between properties and messages and would crash if you tried to access a non-existant property, making the idea of accessing properties with the dot operator vs using messages actually useful and verbose...